# Can I not use the mobos integrated graphics with a Intel Celeron G4900?

Tags: motherboard, nas, intel-celeron, igp

I'm building an Unraid server for backups. I put everything together today but I can't seem to post.

I'm getting 1 long beep followed by 8 short beeps followed by a brief pause and then 1 more short beep. I read somewhere that this means gpu issues, but I have no GPU installed since I want to use the onboard graphics for installing unraid (and then run it headless), is this not how it works?

I have read other threads of people having similar issues with this mobo but with Xeon CPUs that don't have integrated graphics, I believe the Intel Celeron G4900 does. What am I missing?

My components are:

1. Mobo: [ASUS P10S-M WS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EFR517K)
2. CPU: [Intel Celeron G4900](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07938X457)
3. RAM: [Timetec Hynix IC 8GB DDR4 2400MHz Unbuffered ECC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SD96M4C)

Thanks

Comment: I can't help with the rest of the issue, but yes, it does have integrated graphics. Intel Ark is always the go-to resource for that kind of info - https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/129487/intel-celeron-g4900-processor-2m-cache-3-10-ghz.html

Comment: Thanks, yeah it seems like that should work right? I'm clueless here, I tried switching out the RAM to be sure but that wasn't it.

Comment: https://www.azken.com/download/E12535_P10S-M_WS_Series_UM_V3_WEB.pdf - doesn't cover your specific beep counts

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks your checking! Yeah I also couldn't find it in the user guide.